# Treadpool: Simple example for the wait time and execution time to determine the size of the pool

Tags: multithreading, threadpool

I am trying to find simple examples for what are exactly the wait time and execution time in determining the size of the thread pool. According to brian Goetz:

> For tasks that may wait for I/O to complete -- for example, a task
>   that reads an HTTP request from a socket -- you will want to increase
>   the pool size beyond the number of available processors, because not
>   all threads will be working at all times. Using profiling, you can
>   estimate the ratio of waiting time (WT) to service time (ST) for a
>   typical request. If we call this ratio WT/ST, for an N-processor
>   system, you'll want to have approximately N*(1+WT/ST) threads to keep
>   the processors fully utilized.

I really didn't understand what he meant the Input/output. Who's doing the I/O tasks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagine a task that reads some data from disk. What actually happens:

1. Open file.
2. Wait for (the spinning) disk to awake from sleep, to position the head at the right spot and for the desired blocks to appear underneath the head until all bytes arrive in a buffer.
3. Read from the buffer.

The whole task takes 0.1s to complete. Of this 0.1s 10 percent are spent on step 1 and 3 and the remaining 90 percent on step 2. So 0.01s are "working time" and 0.09s "wait time" that is spent waiting for the disk.